# Test the client socket is still alive in C

Tags: c, sockets

`client_sock_fd` is the file descriptor which returned from `accept()`, and here is my code in the server:

```
char buff[BUFFSIZE];
FILE* rstream = fdopen(client_sock_fd, "r");

if(rstream == NULL){
    perror("create read stream failure");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/* how to exit block when client shutdown the socket */
while(fscanf(rstream, "%s", buff) != EOF){
    printf("%s\n", buff);
}

fclose(rstream);
close(client_sock_fd);
```

When I close the socket in the client or may some errors happen so that shutting the client socket down, but, in the server, it is blocked in `fscanf(rstream, "%s", buff) != EOF`, that means `fscanf()` is blocked and never return.

My question is how to test the connection is still alive before execute the `fscanf()`?

Comment: select() or poll() will tell you if a "read" would block... and can be used to not return until a "read" would NOT block (i.e. socket is disconnected, or there is at least one byte waiting to be read)

Comment: What does "when I close the socket in the client or may some errors happen" mean? What errors?

Comment: It means that `close(socket)` is called in the client or the network fall into a crash.

Comment: When the client closes the socket, `fscanf()` will detect end of stream. When the network crashes it may *block* forever, which you can cure by setting a socket read timeout via `setsockopt()` and the `SO_RCVTIMEO` option. In neither case will it loop forever.

Comment: But I found that client closes the socket, `fscanf()` would not detect end of stream. Anyway, using `setsockopt()` to set `SO_RCVTIMEO` taking effects. Thanks!